# Center a grid made out of circles on a webpage

Tags: html, css

How can I go about centering this grid in a webpage? Especially on mobile view it loads very crooked. Not so much an issue when loaded on a larger screen. Mostly just an issue with a mobile device. Thanks. For example, when loaded via mobile the circles are off to the right rather than centered down the screen.

```css
ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
display:grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 220px);
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 220px);
grid-gap:0px;
}

li.small {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:palegreen;
border-radius: 50%;
grid-row:auto / span 1;
grid-column:auto / span 1;
margin:10px 0;
}

li.big {
margin:0;
width:400px;
height:400px;
background-color:black;
border-radius: 50%;
grid-row:auto / span 2;
grid-column: auto / span 2
}
li {
display:block;
padding:0;
margin:0;
align-self:center;
justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="big"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="big"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="big"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
<li class="small"></li>
       

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin: 0 auto` for `li.small` and `li.big` for centering this grid.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ekzm6nr9/) is the jsfiddle.

Comment: What about on a mobile view? It's fine how it is for a webpage but when I view on mobile it shifts

Comment: You are still getting issue in mobile even after adding this style?

Comment: What kind of media queries could I use to overcome this?

Comment: li.big has a width of 400px. So set the min-width of <ul> to 400px. But below 400px (smaller screens), there will be scroll due to this. To overcome this, its better to reduce the size of li.big and set min-width of <ul> tag accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: could you show me this using a jsfiddle or something?